# AS3 - how to get mouse events on embedded bitmaps?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm embedding an image, creating a grid, and trying to cast each embedded image as a DisplayObject so I can use MouseEvents on each image in the grid, however, I can't get a mouseEvent to work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I think I'm missing something simple perhaps.

```
public class ImageGrid extends Sprite
{

    private var gridItems:Array;
    private var grid:Sprite;
    private var sprite:Sprite
    private var reveals:uint = 0;
    private var exceededNumReveals:SimpleText;

    [Embed(source="../Assets/images/tile-grad5-108.png")] 
    public var imgCls:Class;

    public function ImageGrid(tileSize:Number, numTiles:Number, rows:Number)
    {               
        gridItems = new Array();
        grid = new Sprite();
        addChild(grid);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < numTiles; i++) {

            gridItems[i] = new imgCls() as DisplayObject;
            trace(gridItems[i] is DisplayObject) //true
            gridItems[i].rotation = 180
            gridItems[i].x =  (i % rows) *  (tileSize)      
            gridItems[i].y = int(i / rows) *  (tileSize) 
            gridItems[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gridItemClick, false, 0, false);
            grid.addChild(gridItems[i]);
        }       

    }           


    private function gridItemClick (event:MouseEvent):void {
        trace(event.currentTarget);
            reveals ++

        if (reveals < AssetManager.numReveals) {
            TweenLite.to(event.currentTarget, 0.5, {y:900,rotation:Math.random() * 360, ease:Sine.easeOut});
        } else {

            exceededNumReveals = new SimpleText ('You have exceeded your number of reveals', false, false, null, true, true, false, null, null, 20, 'right');
            exceededNumReveals.y = this.y + 300;
            exceededNumReveals.x = this.x + 30;
            addChild(exceededNumReveals)

        }

    }
}
}
```

Here is how I fixed it:

```
    public function ImageGrid(tileSize:Number, numTiles:Number, rows:Number)
    {   

        gridItems = new Array();
        grid = new Sprite();
        addChild(grid);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < numTiles; i++) {

            var imageHolder:Sprite = new Sprite()
            gridItems[i] = new imgCls() as DisplayObject;
            gridItems[i].rotation = 180
            gridItems[i].x =  (i % rows) *  (tileSize)      
            gridItems[i].y = int(i / rows) *  (tileSize) 
            imageHolder.addChild(gridItems[i]);
            imageHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gridItemClick,      false, 0, false);
            grid.addChild(imageHolder);
        }       

    }
```

Comment: You don't have anything imported, could that be the problem?

Comment: no - I just couldn't get them to format correctly in the text box...thought maybe StackExchange was omitting them.  The images load and the grid works like it's supposed to...just can't get an event when I click em.  Thanks!

Comment: Consider putting them in a moviclip and adding the click event to the movieclip

Comment: putting them in a sprite fixed it. Thanks.  if you want to answer I'll check it as correct.

Comment: I'll be glad to put it as an answer, if you put the code.  Wrap it in backticks(`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in an interactive object (MovieClip, Sprite, etc.) to add a Mouse Click Event to them.  Bitmaps are *not* interactive objects.

Answer (score 0):

bitmaps are not interactive objects, you will have to add the listener to the parent